# Do I need to know asp.net to create website using asp.net inside visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I think visual studio is wysiwyg like editor so do I need to learn programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to if you need to add dynamic functionality to your asp.net website.

WYSIWYG if just in terms of visual, like dropping Buttons and layout of the form. For functionality, you are required to code in either C# or VB.net

Answer (score 1):

Unless you just want to design a set of static pages, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Lightswitch:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "website".

For anything more complex than some static pages you're going to need to learn some kind of programming.

Even with a basic site you'll want to learn CSS and HTML. The code produced by any WYSIWYG is rarely up to standard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to learn programming, in some form or the other. If you're just looking to create some static HTML pages, you should probably look into something like Dreamweaver instead of Visual Studio. The learning curve with Dreamweaver isn't as steep.